# less option "--save-marks" does nothing when less is used as a manual pager

Tags: man, less, pager

I use `less` version 590 (GNU regular expressions).

I use

```
export LESSFILE="/root/.lesshst_for_manpages"
export MANPAGER="pager --save-marks -I"
man -L en <<somemanpage>>
```

... but `--save-marks` appears to have no effect when setting marks in manuals (using the `m` command in the pager).  When reading the same manual again, the pager does not seem to remember the previously set marks.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `less` with `--save-marks`, set a few marks in the file called `file`, and quit the pager, your `~/.lesshst` files will contain a few lines of information about these marks:

```bash
$ cat ~/.lesshst
.less-history-file:
.mark
m a 1 6659 /home/myself/tmp/file
m c 1 33259 /home/myself/tmp/file
```

Here, I've set the `a` and `c` marks at different locations using the `m` command in `less`, in the file `~/tmp/file`.  As you can see, the two marks are tied to the pathname of the file.  This allows us to view the same file in `less` at some later time, and go to either the `a` or `c` mark using the `'` command.

Setting the `a` and `b` marks in another file will update the saved `a` mark and add the `b` mark:

```bash
$ cat ~/.lesshst
.less-history-file:
.mark
m a 1 46559 /home/myself/tmp/other-file
m b 1 13309 /home/myself/tmp/other-file
m c 1 33259 /home/myself/tmp/file
```

Note that the `a` mark in the `~/tmp/file` file no longer exists.
The *point* is that the marks are locations in files at particular pathnames.

When you use `less` as a pager for reading manuals, what is the pathname of the text document you read?  You can get this information using either the `=` command, the `:f` command, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> in the pager.  A hint: There is no filename.

The reason there is no filename is because the manual, i.e., the text document that `less` is displaying, is coming from a pipe.  It's similar to using `less` like so:

```bash
$ cat file | less --save-marks
```

... and if you do that, and set a mark, you will notice that the mark is removed from the `.mark` section of the `~/.lesshst`.

In short, `less` cannot remember a mark in a piped document.  This is why marks are not saved when using `less` for viewing manuals. Furthermore, any marks that you *try* to set in a manual will be *cleared* from your `~/.lesshst` file.

Answer (score -1):

you are probably looking for:

`export LESSHISTFILE="..." ...`

And do you have the needed privileges for writing into `/root/.less...`?

Did that help?

Comment: no, my question --save-marks is not related to LESSHISTFILE. This was only accidentally in my example. Regards.